# Error when attempting to add bot to xcode server: "This server cannot build for any platform"

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server

Currently can't add a bot to an xcode server and I'm encountering the following error:

[Xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QPzp.png)

I'm using the latest version of xcode (7.1 7B91b) and OS X server (5.0.15 15S4033) and have not had any luck finding a solution after searching stack overflow or the apple developer forums. I'm able to successfully add the server to a developer machine but the bot creation fails and gives the above error message whenever I get past the screen where you specify the continuous integration interval for xcode server.

Here is the stack trace:

```
  Nov  6 17:45:47 NYCC02PX0LCG8WL com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git[4412]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/_xcsd/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git. Errno:2
Nov  6 17:45:47 NYCC02PX0LCG8WL com.apple.SecurityServer[94]: Session 100033 created
Nov  6 17:45:47 NYCC02PX0LCG8WL com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git[4414]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/_xcsd/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git. Errno:2

Nov  6 17:39:50 NYCC02PX0LCG8WL xcscontrol[98]:  ERROR XCSControlCommandLineTool: Got an error persisting version information: Error Domain=XCSCoreDomain Code=503 "Xcode Server is unavailable" UserInfo=0x7f9de1c07a20 {NSLocalizedDescription=Xcode Server is unavailable, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Check your network connection or contact your server administrator for help.}

Nov  6 17:39:50 NYCC02PX0LCG8WL com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.service.xcode[280]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Nov  6 17:39:50 NYCC02PX0LCG8WL com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.service.xcode): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Comment: Can you check the console logs to see if an error message there might have more detail? I just tried the process with the same xcode version and didn't have a problem.

Comment: Which log from OS X server is most useful?

Comment: Select All Messages then search for XCode.

Comment: Well it looks like a server issue. I would  turn off xcode in os x server, quit os x server, reboot, restart server and then turn on xcode again.

Comment: Still encountering the same issue and have tried many different things.

Comment: Does the console log still show the same errors? BTW: I confirmed that you and are one exactly the same versions of both Server and XCode.

Comment: Starting to think it might be the network itself. Will report back after attempting on a different network.

Answer (score 0):

I had to connect iOS device to XCode Server machine – then it started working fine.

Even if you remove iOS device later, you can still create bots. It was only first time I had to connect.